# Why is only one field saved when I use entity_metadata_wrapper()?

Tags: entities

I'm using `entity_metadata_wrapper()` to access entityform fields in my module's form, including a field collection I will need to save to.

However, for some reasons, I can't fathom why only the last element in the field collection in my entityform is actually saved. I'm collecting the form data fine, and setting it fine (as reported back by `dsm()`), but the wrapper saves only the last value.

This is the code I am using.

```
function investment_lineitems_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // The entityform ID is passed as URL argument.
  $entityform = array_pop(arg());
  // Fetch the specific entityform.
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('entityform', $entityform);
  // Use this counter to read back the numbered fields in form.
  $collection_count = 0; 

  foreach ($wrapper->field_inv_account_details as $field_collection_wrapper) {
    // Cycle through each line in the field collection.
    // Increment the counter on each loop; the first one is 1.
    $collection_count++;
    // Grab the value from the form field.
    $collection_item_value = $form_state['input']['edit_your_percent_amount_' . $collection_count];
    // Check we're getting the correct value. (We are.) 
    dsm("collection item value: ". $collection_count ." = " . $collection_item_value);
    // Set the new value in the field collection field.
    $field_collection_wrapper->field_inv_your_percent_split_a->set($collection_item_value);  
    // Check we've set the correct value. (We have.)
    dsm($field_collection_wrapper->field_inv_your_percent_split_a->value());
  }

  // The following should save all items in the field collection.
  // This should save the field collection, but only the last field
  // collection item is being written to the database.
  $field_collection_wrapper->save();

  drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted.'));
}
```

Why is only one field saved?

Answer (score 0):

The `$field_collection_wrapper->save();` command shouldn't be outside the `foreach` loop. That's why it's only catching the last item processed. Moving it inside the loop should solve the problem.